# How to configure rvm with netbeans

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, rvm

I have installed ruby 1.9.2-p1890 in my rvm and the gem directory is

```
/Users/abhay/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
```

My netbeans detected the rvm and the ruby installed but when i right click the project properies->manage

```
gem home is - /Users/abhay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1

gem path is - /Users/abhay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1

gem tool is - /Users/abhay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/gem (1.8.24)

interpreter - /Users/abhay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
```

and when I run my project, I get this error

```
  /Users/abhay/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- script/server (LoadError)
```